# Freemember ID number error

Tags: freemember

I'm getting the following error using the password reset after following the email link:

> The form you submitted contained the following errors
>
> The ID number you submitted does not appear to be valid. Please check
>   the link you followed.

Is this an EE problem or Freemembe? If Freemember what do I need to do to fix it?

Thanks,

Andrew

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by adding the 'Reset password' tag. Not sure if there is another option.